# Applying for B2 visa for my parents: my mother's surname in her passport is different from the name in my dad's passport [spouse section]

Tags: indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas

I'm currently working in the US and I would like to apply for a B2 visa for my parents.

While filling up the DS 160 for my dad, I realized my mother's surname in his passport in the spouse section is "Z" whereas while getting her passport we used the surname "Y".

First, I wanted to know if this will create any problems if they both go to the visa interview together. If not, then while filling up the spouse section in the DS-160 for my dad, should the surname of my mom be the one in his passport or her passport?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which one is her legal name?

Comment: The one on her passport!

Comment: Use the name on her passport and have her dads passport corrected to avoid future confusions

Answer (score 4):

The one on the passport she will carry is the reference you need to use unless a name change has been officially processed but not yet on the passport

You do also need to put her other name on the "other names" field in the application for her

Comment: That means in my dad's DS160 spouse name will be the actual name on the spouse's passport and not the one in my dad's passport right?

Comment: @Anu Yes, exactly